# Vaadin setting TextFIeld value in a Panel class

Tags: vaadin

I have a problem in setting Textfield value in a class that extended Panel.
Heres my code.

```
package com.example.examplejpa;

import com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.ui.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;

public class PersonnalInfoPanel extends Panel
{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 680441095924886309L;
    private TextField claimantName;
    private TextField insuredName;
    private TextField dateofbirth;
    private TextField age;
    private TextField dateFrom;
    private TextField dateTo;
    private TextField noDays;
    private ComboBox cause;
    private SearchButton searchBtn = new SearchButton();


    public PersonnalInfoPanel ()
    {

        setCaption("PERSONAL DATA INFO");
        setWidth("500px");

        FormLayout form = new FormLayout();
        form.setSpacing(true);
        form.setMargin(true);

        form.addComponent(searchBtn);

        claimantName = new TextField();
        claimantName.setCaption("Claimant Name");
        claimantName.setWidth("70%");
        form.addComponent(claimantName);

        insuredName = new TextField();
        insuredName.setCaption("Insured Name");
        insuredName.setWidth("70%");
        form.addComponent(insuredName);

        HorizontalLayout dateAge = new HorizontalLayout();
        dateAge.setSpacing(true);
        dateAge.setWidth("70%");

        dateofbirth = new TextField();
        dateofbirth.setCaption("Date of Birth");
        dateofbirth.setWidth("100%");
        dateAge.addComponent(dateofbirth);

        age = new TextField();
        age.setCaption("Age");
        age.setWidth("100%");
        dateAge.addComponent(age);

        form.addComponent(dateAge);

        HorizontalLayout dateRange = new HorizontalLayout();
        dateRange.setSpacing(true);
        dateRange.setWidth("70%");

        dateFrom = new TextField();
        dateFrom.setCaption("Date From");
        dateFrom.setWidth("100%");
        dateRange.addComponent(dateFrom);

        dateTo = new TextField();
        dateTo.setCaption("Date To");
        dateTo.setWidth("100%");
        dateRange.addComponent(dateTo);
        form.addComponent(dateRange);

        noDays = new TextField();
        noDays.setCaption("No. of Days");
        noDays.setWidth("70%");
        form.addComponent(noDays);

        cause = new ComboBox();
        cause.setCaption("Cause");
        cause.setWidth("70%");
        form.addComponent(cause);

        setContent(form);

    }

    public void setInsuredName (String newInsureName) { this.insuredName.setValue(newInsureName); }
    public void setClaimantName (String newClaimantName) { this.claimantName.setValue("awd"); System.out.println(newClaimantName); }
    public void setDateofbirth (String newDateofbirth) { this.dateofbirth.setValue(newDateofbirth); }
    public void setAge (String newAge) { this.age.setValue(newAge); }
    public void setDateFrom (String newDateFrom) { this.dateFrom.setValue(newDateFrom); }
    public void setDateTo (String newDateTo) { this.dateTo.setValue(newDateTo); }
    public void setNoDay (String newNoDay) { this.noDays.setValue(newNoDay); }

    public TextField getClaimantName () { return this.claimantName; }
}
```

But when I access its setter method to set value for specific Component, it does nothing, still the value is empty..

Comment: please provide the (minimal) code, that shows the actual problem.

Comment: Where are you calling this setter from?

Comment: Please provide more detail.Where you have added the panel? please show Method call..

Answer (score 0):

I finally got answer to this question..
But my technique is I made my main class has an static method which calls the panels getter and setter methods.. thats how I solve my problem.. but it is a appropriate to do it ?